# Is there a more efficient way of achieving this update using linq?

Tags: linq

By efficient, I'm referring to resources.

```
foreach (var n in ActiveNodes.Where(x => userApplications.Any(y => y.BuyerId == x.BuyerID)))
{
    n.Status = PingtreeStatus.Duplicate;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. I was simply asking if there was a better more efficient way other than using the foreach loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq is for *querying* not *updating*.  Your method is perfectly fine as-is.  Linq would allow you to create a *new* collection with different property values (saving some of the overhead of creating a new object, adding it ti a list, etc.), but it is not designed to update a collection in-place.

Comment: It is *possible* to update the values of objects within a collection using Linq, something like `var update = collection.Select(o => o.Value = newValue).ToList();`.  **However** I would personally not update a collection in this way.

Comment: It's _possible_ but it's not designed to do that.  It's like a `SELECT` in SQL - you can write one that has side-effects, but that's not the standard practice.